# make an html and javascript to classified person based on their age

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do my JavaScript revision but I got stuck to this question. is there a simple code of html and JavaScript to achieve the answers to these question?

[image: the question]

I have tried a simple look of html and JavaScript. but since I am a beginner. some words in this question I may find it hard.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="js/age.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var msg;
    if (age == 0 && age <= 2) {
      msg = "Toddler";
    } else if (age == 3 && age <= 11) {
      msg = "Child";
    } else if (age == 12 && age <= 17) {
      msg = "Adolescent";
    } else {
      msg = "Adult";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
  }
</script>

<body> Age: <input type="text"> <button onsubmit="return myFunction()">Find Category</button> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is "these question"? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: the question is in the picture. this what i have tried so far : <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="js/age.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var msg;
    if (age ==0  && age=>2) {
  msg = "Toddler";
 }
    else if (age ==3  && age=>11) {
  msg = "Child";
 }
    else if (age ==12  && age=>17) {
  msg = "Adolescent";
 }
    else {
  msg = "Adult";
 }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =msg;
}
</script>
<body>
Age: <input type="text">
<button onsubmit="return myFunction()">Find Category</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Also [how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `=>` MUST be the other way around: `>=` but you likely mean `<=` as in less or equal

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about that code? Anything not working as expected?

Comment: Also it is form onsubmit and button onclick. But look at [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: Lastly you need to get the age from the field: `const age = document.getElementById("age").value;` where you add `id="age"` to the input field

Comment: i still can't figured it out, how and where do i need to put the code containing all the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. less than or equal is <=  - the `=>` is called a fat arrow and used in the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#arrow_functions) below
2. onclick is the event, but use an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
3. You do not store the age from the input field
4. You do not have a demo element

Here is a better script. Please study it.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded
  const findButton = document.getElementById("find");
  const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  findButton.addEventListener("click", e => { // clicking the button
    let msg;
    let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 2) {
      msg = "Toddler";
    } else if (age >= 3 && age <= 11) {
      msg = "Child";
    } else if (age >= 12 && age <= 17) {
      msg = "Adolescent";
    } else {
      msg = "Adult";
    }
    demo.innerHTML = msg;
  });
});
```

```html
Age: <input type="text" id="age"> <button type="button" id="find">Find Category</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: thank you so much ! its much easier than i thought. but i have one last question. rather than using eventListener. is there any other alternative?

Comment: Yes - onclick of the button or onsubmit of a wrapping form. But it is not recommended